# Improve SQL Server query performance on large tables MsSQL vs MySQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2017

i am having production system running on latest MsSQL, however i am getting very bad performance for simple select statement when there is a lot of rows (10M+).

There is no such thing as hash index in MsSQL (as far as I know) so in my question i compare MySQL community database and MSSQL 2017 running on the same machine with the exception that MySQL runs under windows ubuntu virtual machine.

In sample script i create 100 million rows and execute it. In MS SQL the performance is so bad that the simple query took almost 2 seconds. In MySQL the query took 0.0011 sec. I assume that MS SQL should be better than free MySQL so i expect i miss something with indexing.

Can somebody please advise me how to create more efficient index with MsSQL?

Test table MSSQL:

```
drop table if exists [dbo].[TEST_TRADE];


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEST_TRADE](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TradeID] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [ValidFrom] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL,
    [ValidUntil] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL,
)
GO  

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_Primary   
    ON [dbo].[TEST_TRADE] ([ID]);   
GO  

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_TradeID   
    ON [dbo].[TEST_TRADE] ([TradeID]);   
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_ValidUntil   
    ON [dbo].[TEST_TRADE] ([ValidUntil]);   
GO

Declare @Id int
Set @Id = 1

While @Id <= 100000000
Begin 
   Insert Into [dbo].[TEST_TRADE] ([TradeID]) values (
   'ID'+CAST(@Id as nvarchar(10))),(
   'ID'+CAST(@Id+1 as nvarchar(10))),(
   'ID'+CAST(@Id+2 as nvarchar(10))),(
   'ID'+CAST(@Id+3 as nvarchar(10))),(
   'ID'+CAST(@Id+4 as nvarchar(10))),(
   'ID'+CAST(@Id+5 as nvarchar(10))),(
   'ID'+CAST(@Id+6 as nvarchar(10))),(
   'ID'+CAST(@Id+7 as nvarchar(10))),(
   'ID'+CAST(@Id+8 as nvarchar(10))),(
   'ID'+CAST(@Id+9 as nvarchar(10))),(
   'ID'+CAST(@Id+10 as nvarchar(10))),(
   'ID'+CAST(@Id+11 as nvarchar(10))),(
   'ID'+CAST(@Id+12 as nvarchar(10))),(
   'ID'+CAST(@Id+13 as nvarchar(10))),(
   'ID'+CAST(@Id+14 as nvarchar(10))),(
   'ID'+CAST(@Id+15 as nvarchar(10))),(
   'ID'+CAST(@Id+16 as nvarchar(10))),(
   'ID'+CAST(@Id+17 as nvarchar(10))),(
   'ID'+CAST(@Id+18 as nvarchar(10))),(
   'ID'+CAST(@Id+19 as nvarchar(10))
   )
   Print @Id
   Set @Id = @Id + 20
End
```

MySQL test table:

```
drop table if exists `Test`.`TEST_TRADE`;
CREATE TABLE `Test`.`TEST_TRADE` ( `ID` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `TradeID` VARCHAR(250) NULL default null, `ValidFrom` TIMESTAMP NULL default null, `ValidUntil` TIMESTAMP NULL default null, PRIMARY KEY (`ID`), INDEX (`TradeID`) USING HASH, INDEX (`ValidUntil`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

drop PROCEDURE if EXISTS InsertRand;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertRand(IN NumRows INT)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE i INT;
        SET i = 1;
        START TRANSACTION;
        WHILE i <= NumRows DO
            INSERT INTO TEST_TRADE(TradeID) VALUES 
            (concat("ID",i)),
            (concat("ID",i+1)),
            (concat("ID",i+2)),
            (concat("ID",i+3)),
            (concat("ID",i+4)),
            (concat("ID",i+5)),
            (concat("ID",i+6)),
            (concat("ID",i+7)),
            (concat("ID",i+8)),
            (concat("ID",i+9)),
            (concat("ID",i+10)),
            (concat("ID",i+11)),
            (concat("ID",i+12)),
            (concat("ID",i+13)),
            (concat("ID",i+14)),
            (concat("ID",i+15)),
            (concat("ID",i+16)),
            (concat("ID",i+17)),
            (concat("ID",i+18)),
            (concat("ID",i+19))
            ;
            SET i = i + 20;
        END WHILE;
        COMMIT;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL InsertRand(100000000);
```

[image: SQL Profiler execution]

[image: MySQL execution]

Comment: Hash indexes are avaiable in SQL Server but only on memory-optimized tables but that might note be the right solution. Add the query that takes 2 seconds to your question. Even better, upload the actual execution plan to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/.

Comment: If your queries are mpostly by `TradeID`, I think that should be the custered index instead of `ID`.

Comment: How do i detect actual execution plan?

TradeID is not unique because we track information with validity times and track the time from which row is valid, so there might be multiple TradeID rows in the table.

Comment: The clustered index does not need to be unique nor does it have to be the primary key. You can run the query from SSMS with the actual execution plan option. Right-click on the graphical view to see the XML and upload it to the site.

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJhnR0pMB
this execution plan took in profiler 60ms (i might have run the 2 sec query at bad time probably.. i was not able to achieve this delay, or the first run of the query was reindexing index)
Most of the queries when i run it now i receive good latency (1-60ms). With this examples i tried to simulate what we have on production system. There we do not get data in less then 100 ms which when we want to do update of items consumes whole CPU..

Memory tables are not an option as we do not have enough ram.

Comment: The time taken of the single row query is pribably due to physical IO, which will likely occur with large tables that won't fit into memory. I expect the same query will run much faster the second time due to caching. With a clusterered index, fewer logical (and physical) IOs will be needed, cutting time in half.

Comment: You comment about updating items consuming all CPU in production is concerning, although unrelated to your question.

Comment: You used a stored procedure in MySQL, but did not in MSSQL.  Is there any reason you would do so?

Comment: @Zorkolot .. it does not matter, it was just used to generate random data

Comment: @DanGuzman How is CPU not related to this issue? In the profiler in column CPU is in my opinion large number, when you run 1000 queries asap i get CPU bottleneck...

Comment: @DanGuzman .. Cluster index is not an option because as docs says: "There can be only one clustered index per table" 
Basically with the Validity information i mostly need to select valid items, so the real query is usually "TradeID = '..' and ValidUntil is null"  and with data values OtherColumn = 'value' and ValidUntil is null

Or better something like 

(TradeID = '$id' and ValidFrom <= @ time and (ValidUntil is null or ValidUntil > @ time))

So basically i need multiple columns where some of them might be more efficient if there would be something like HASH index.

Comment: I have not seen any HASH index even in SQL 2019 RC.. am i right?

Comment: @Scholtz, the implication is you will need to drop the PK `ID` index, create a clustered index on `TradeId`, and then recreate the `ID` primary key as nonclustered. HASH indexes in SQL Server are only allowed in in-memory tables and efficient for equality lookups but not range searches.

Comment: Regarding the CPU issue, I suspect it may be due do to Profiler overhead. Instead, consider a [server-side trace](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/steps/stairway-to-server-side-tracing-level-3-creating-a-sql-trace-using-sql-server-profiler) or doing the same with an Extended Event Trace.

Comment: @Scholtz, FYI, I ran a test with your original indexes with query `SELECT * FROM dbo.TEST_TRADE WHERE TradeID = 'ID99999999' AND ValidUntil IS NULL;`. It took 33 seconds to execute 100K queries with 4 client threads (3000/sec) and the server CPU (6 cores/12 threads) never exceeded 10%. I repeated the test with the clustered index and got the same results, even though the logical IO was cut in half. Network latency was the long pole in the tent.

Comment: In the example, you pre-compile and eliminate overhead in the MySQL example by using a stored procedure.  The plan is cached on the server- executed almost outright.  You did not do the same in the SQL Server example so it's not a fair comparison.  You need to run the SP in SQL Server at least once to compile to see future benefits.

Comment: You are also printing the value of @id to console in SQL Server but not doing so in MySQL.  Printing the output in that manner will always take extra time especially if looping 5 million times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are selecting 10m + rows, data size per row for you SQL server table is 42 bytes.
(bigint = 8 bytes) + (varchar of 12 chars = 14 bytes) + (datetimeoffset = 10 bytes)*2
So 10 million rows should be 420 000 000 bytes which is aproximate 400MB.

So reading 400MB data in 2 sec is 400MB/2s = 200MB/s, which is a reasonable speed for accessing hard drive. 
But 400MB/0.0011s is 363 636,36MB/s, that is way beyond any hard drive speed and very similar to the RAM accessing speed.

So the table in MySQL must be fully cached in Memory and that is why your query can be finshed at 0.0011 sec.

You need to find a way to cached you MsSQL table fully in Memory too in order to achieve similar speed.

Edited: 
If your query is

```
Select * FROM [dbo].[TEST_TRADE]
where [TradeId] = 'ID99999999'
```

Create clustered index on column [TradeId] first, then create PK on [ID], and if possible, use fixed length char(12) for [TradeId] instread of varchar.

Edited:

Tested, making a clustered index on column [TradeId] will speed the query up to 50%.

And I would suggest to check the index fragmentation for [IX_TradeID] first and rebuild the index regularly.

Comment: Well.. MySQL is not fully in memory because the mysql process has less ram then the table.

Comment: The data structure of production tables is not so simple... Do you believe that adding the search index as first should do some significant change? How can we search by other indexes of some value columns with real data..

Comment: clustered index is faster than nonclustered index. And check the IX_TradeID fragmentation first.

Comment: cluster index may be used only once in the table, so it means that mysql is superior in technology to mssql because it has the hash index?
inability of efficient search on any critical value column is critical in many application.. i dont understand why microsoft does not do this, and yet it seems pretty simple.. to create a table with pointers on hash value

Comment: Hash index is stored with 'key', 'value' structure and not B-Tree like traditional index. It is very fast for query like yours, but you cannot gain any performance for 'LIKE' clause search, or 'order by' on hash index.  In this scenario, I do agree hash index is superior to B-Tree.

Comment: check this, is possible to convert your table to memory-optimized table and then you can use hash index on TradeID.  https://www.arbinada.com/en/node/1642

Comment: yes, there can be only one clustered index, so you need to drop the current clustered index first and then create clustered index on TradeID, and create nonclustered index on ID back.

Comment: According to https://www.arbinada.com/en/node/1642, hashed index is 7 times faster than nonclustered index and 4 times faster than clustered index. So you should expect around 70ms for nonclustered index and 40ms for clustered index with you query, assuming no fragmentaion on the index nor other issues evolved.